# VLOOKUP on part of multiple text strings

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two lists: an input list and a reference list (in a 2nd tab).
I would like to append the input list based on the reference, but based on a string within the input and not the whole input field.
Have been looking around vlookup, find, match, arrays, but just cannot get it right.

Example: I want to add the country of origin on a list of books, based on the author

**Input Tab (1 column, no writing convention):**

```
1984 (George Orwell)  
Ethan Frome by Edith Wharton  
Hamlet, William Shakespeare  
Murder on the Orient Express [Agatha Christie]  
The Murder of Roger Ackroyd by Agatha Christie  
Pride and Prejudice; Jane Austen  
Little Women - Louisa May Alcott  
Aesop's Fables  
Anne Frank: The Diary of a Young Girl
```

**Reference Tab:**

```
col A Authors - col B Country  
Aesop              Greece  
Agatha Christie    UK  
Anne Frank         Germany  
Edith Wharton      USA  
George Orwell      UK  
Jane Austen        UK  
Louisa May Alcott   USA  
William Shakespeare UK
```

[image: Authors & Country]

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Your screenshot is the same as the table above?

Comment: Pls choose either excel or google sheets.

Comment: Maybe this is lack of my knowledge but there seem to be a lot of scenarios to cover here just to extract author's name. You could use a very heavy formula or VBA to do this but i suspect what you need is an algorithm (that's walking into AI). It might be worth looking into how the `Input` table gathers it's information and try something on that end

Comment: CAn you share a sample sheet with what you have tried?

Comment: @JvdV Preference for Excel, but I could use Google Sheets if it's a better option

Comment: @SJR yes, wasn't necessary indeed :-)

Comment: @Aerials It was Google + trial and errors, I didn't save any as it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the spreadsheet is a google spreadsheet, see if this works

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), vlookup(regexextract(A2:A, textjoin("|", 1, Sheet27!A2:A9)), Sheet27!A2:B9, 2, 0),))
```

Replace Sheet27 with the name of your reference tab and change range to suit.

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks, but I must have missed something  
Book Country  
1984 (George Orwell) #ERROR!

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet so I can have a closer look?

Comment: Thanks, a 2nd look with fresh eyes gave me the solution, I removed a blank space and it worked :o